# How to make dedication page and move words to the middle?

Tags: spacing, thesis

I am newbie to Latex.

I am writing thesis for graduation, and have met problems for making

1. dedication page.
2. words move to the middle.

With files in zip file in below URL, wish list to solve are
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwaXGDzwOYJsLW5MNjJ3djJWeFk/view?usp=sharing

1. I want to make dedication page in cls file like 'dedication page example'  picture before abstract page with italic fonts.
2. Like pic 1, words are much spaced along vertical line. I want edit this page  like the pic 2 format. we can see that pic 2 has balanced space with title,  name, sentence month and names.

please give any solutions to me.

Thank you

Comment: Please do not change a cls file.

Comment: It seems you are having two completely different and unrelated questions, please ask them separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following sets the text vertically and horizontally centered within the text block.

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\begin{center}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    To my beloved Mara
    \vspace*{\fill}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```